# Detect end of FlipView animation

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

`FlipView`'s `SelectionChanged` event is fired when the animation starts. How can I let the animation end before executing code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, but you could try this :

```
await Task.Delay(animation time for example 1 sec.);
```

before the execution of selection changed event!

Comment: Thanks, but no. The animation of a FlipView depends on user interaction and can be long or short. I'm looking for an actual event.